# "this website is not available" using symfony

Tags: symfony, wampserver

I have a localhost on this computer, with a "local domain" that is: `mywebsite.loc`.  The server i'm running is the wamp server 2.2D and works perfectly..

i'm just getting started with symfony so perhaps I missed a step somewhere...

I downloaded the `symfony standard (without vendors)` package from their site.  I then extracted the archive and moved the files to my project folder..

Since I downloaded the version without any vendors, I have to install those.  So from the command line I ran: `php bin/vendors install` and all standard vendors installed perfectly with no errors..

Just as a check to see if the local server is properly equipped to handle apache, I run: `php app/check.php` which comes out with the following:

```
********************************
*                              *
*  Symfony requirements check  *
*                              *
********************************

php.ini used by PHP: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\php.ini

** WARNING **
*  The PHP CLI can use a different php.ini file
*  than the one used with your web server.
*  (especially on the Windows platform)
*  If this is the case, please ALSO launch this
*  utility from your web server.
** WARNING **

** Mandatory requirements **

  OK        Checking that PHP version is at least 5.3.2 (5.3.10 installed)
  OK        Checking that the "date.timezone" setting is set
  OK        Checking that app/cache/ directory is writable
  OK        Checking that the app/logs/ directory is writable
  OK        Checking that the json_encode() is available
  OK        Checking that the SQLite3 or PDO_SQLite extension is available
  OK        Checking that the session_start() is available
  OK        Checking that the ctype_alpha() is available
  OK        Checking that the token_get_all() is available
  OK        Checking that the APC version is at least 3.0.17

** Optional checks **

  OK        Checking that the PHP-XML module is installed
  OK        Checking that the token_get_all() function is available
  OK        Checking that the mb_strlen() function is available
  OK        Checking that the iconv() function is available
  OK        Checking that the utf8_decode() is available
  OK        Checking that the intl extension is available
  OK        Checking that the intl ICU version is at least 4+


[[WARNING]] Checking that a PHP accelerator is installed: FAILED
            *** Install a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended) ***
  OK        Checking that php.ini has short_open_tag set to off
  OK        Checking that php.ini has magic_quotes_gpc set to off
  OK        Checking that php.ini has register_globals set to off
  OK        Checking that php.ini has session.auto_start set to off

** Optional checks (Doctrine) **

  OK        Checking that PDO is installed
  OK        Checking that PDO has some drivers installed: mysql, sqlite
```

As you can see everything is good other than not having a PHP accelerator installed on my local machine..  In my vhosts config file, I have tried with the `DocumentRoot` being `project_directory/` and `project_directory/web/`

When it's set to just the standard `project_directory/` I get the directory listing in the browser, but when I traverse into the web folder, the `.htaccess` picks up and takes me to app.php.

So either way, when I try and load app.php or app_dev.php I get the following:

> This webpage is not available The connection to mywebsite.loc was
>   interrupted.

and I've got no clue how to fix that...  Any help I can get would be awesome..  I'll try anything to get it working..

[EDIT]

```
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\RouterListener::onEarlyKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] request.INFO: Matched route "_welcome" (parameters: "_controller": "Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\WelcomeController::indexAction", "_route": "_welcome") [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-03-31 19:32:54] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Controller\ControllerListener::onCoreController". [] []
```

[EDIT1]

```
[Sat Mar 31 11:54:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache2, referer: http://mywebsite.loc/
[Sat Mar 31 11:54:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache2, referer: http://mywebsite.loc/
[Sat Mar 31 11:54:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache2, referer: http://mywebsite.loc/
[Sat Mar 31 11:54:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache2, referer: http://mywebsite.loc/
[Sat Mar 31 11:54:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache2, referer: http://mywebsite.loc/
```

[EDIT2]

in httpd.conf i added:

```
<Directory "G:/websites/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

which works for all my other sites (not using symfony)

and my vhost looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "G:/websites/my websites/mywebsite/web/"
    ServerName mywebsite.loc
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.loc
    ErrorLog "logs/mywebsite.loc-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mywebsite.loc-access.log" common
<Directory "G:/websites/my websites/mywebsite/web/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Somewhere, in either the server or something its trying to read C:/Apache2 which doesn't exist.. but I can't find where it is..  so I created the folder and copied over the entire apache folder to it..

but all i get in the logs is:

```
[Sat Mar 31 14:18:01 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: G:/websites/my websites/dpstruck.com/web/app_dev.php
[Sat Mar 31 14:18:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: G:/websites/my websites/dpstruck.com/web/app_dev.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditching wamp altogether and installing each component 1 by 1 did the trick...  Unsure why it wouldn't work with wamp...

Answer (score 0):

It should work using app_dev.php. Set your virtualhost DocumentRoot to project_directory/web

If not working I suggest to check permissions on app/cache and app/logs . Both folders must be writable for the Apache user. Take a look at the Book page:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

If permissions are correct and still doesn´t work, check your app/logs/dev.log and the Apache logs.

**EDIT:**

Probably a virtualhost missconfiguration:

Change this

```
<Directory /path/to/web/root >
Options IndexesFollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

to this

```
<Directory /path/to/web/root >
Options IndexesFollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Source: http://kurinchilamp.kurinchilion.com/2010/04/apache-client-denied-by-server-configuration-error.html

Comment: app_dev.php doesn't work either.  I've tried the DocumentRoot both with and without the /web and no change on either solution..

the book on permissions, doesnt appear to apply to windows users but i have umask(0000); set -- and still nothing..

Comment: Nothing in the apache logs at all for the site..  I edited my question above with the info in the symfony logs file.

Comment: Looks like an incorrect virtualhost configuration. Check this article:  [link](http://kurinchilamp.kurinchilion.com/2010/04/apache-client-denied-by-server-configuration-error.html)

Comment: I get the same error on that link...  if it's an incorrect virtualhost config though, i wouldn't get any directory listings when i visit the page before i click on app.php or app_dev.php

Comment: It is now telling me in the apache logs:
[Sat Mar 31 14:18:01 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: G:/websites/my websites/mywebsite/web/app_dev.php
[Sat Mar 31 14:18:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: G:/websites/my websites/mywebsite/web/app_dev.php

my vhost is edited in my question above..

Comment: I ended up figuring this out, not really but kinda...  I uninstalled wamp, and reinstalled everything 1 component at a time manually..  and it suddenly works...  no idea why symfony doesn't like wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the cause but we have spent several hours on this today. Installing an older version of wamp (2.1) worked.

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't figure it out myself...  I ended up ditching the all-in-one and installing it one by one and it works.. but whats weirder, is my machine at work has 2.2D on it and symfony works on it.. but when i install them all one by one, it wont...  strange.. very strange..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem after defining an addChild() method in an parent class. This method was incompatible with the same children method.

i don't know why, the debugger wouldn't do its job and I had the same connexion refused / this website is not available, etc.

I just had to undo my change and it worked well.